# Prevent deleting of " / " in HTML

Tags: html

When I use below code block for testing, 
I write my original HTML which starts with `<xsl:key name="Name" match="/NewSet/ps1/Name/text()" use="." />` into first box, I get the result from third box which is names "HTML Mode of the IFRAME" like `<xsl:key name="Name" match="/NewSet/ps1/Name/text()" use="." ></xsl:key>`

Result is with out `/`  tag, how can I prevent this problem.

I think this is about text engine of browsers? Isn't it?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Editable IFRAME test</title>
</head>
<body onload="SetEditable()">
    <b>Set your original HTML content here:</b><br />
    <textarea id="htmlArea" style="width: 783px; height: 189px"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateHtml();return false;" value="Set Content in the IFRAME">
    <br />
    <b>Editable IFRAME element:</b>
    <br />
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid red;">
        <iframe style="padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px; padding-left: 0px; width: 100%;
            padding-right: 0px; height: 100%; padding-top: 0px" frameborder="0" src="javascript:void(0)"
            id="editor"></iframe>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="ShowIFRAMEHTML();return false;" value="Show IFRAME HTML">
    <br />
    <b>HTML Mode of the IFRAME:</b>
    <br />
    <textarea id="htmlMode" style="width: 783px; height: 313px"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var editor1 = document.getElementById("editor"); //reference to the IFRAME element
        var htmlArea1 = document.getElementById("htmlArea"); //reference to the HTML area in which we put the content
        var htmlMode = document.getElementById("htmlMode"); //reference to the HTML area that displays the IFRAME content
        var oDocument = editor1.contentWindow.document;

        var sMarkup = "<html><head><title>New Document</title></head>" +
                  "<body contenteditable=true style='overflow:scroll;margin:0px;padding:0px;height:100%'>" +
                  "&nbsp;</body></html>";

        function SetEditable() {
            oDocument.open();
            oDocument.write(sMarkup);
            oDocument.close();
            oDocument["designMode"] = "on";
            oDocument.execCommand("2D-Position", false, true);
        }
        function CreateHtml() {
            oDocument.body.innerHTML = htmlArea1.value;
            htmlMode.value = oDocument.body.innerHTML;
        }
        function ShowIFRAMEHTML() {
            alert(oDocument.body.innerHTML);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of `innerHTML` have you tried using `.innerText` or `.textContent` (e.g. `htmlMode.value = (oDocument.body.innerText || oDocument.body.textContent)` )

Comment: You are right @Pedro Estrada, thank you..

Answer (score 0):

No, it's about how the value for `innerHTML` is created.

You put the HTML code in the iframe, which causes it to parse it into elements. Then you get those elements as HTML, which will create new HTML code from the elemtns, not return the original string that was used to create the elements.

If you test this in different browsers, you will see that you get different results. Some browsers may for example capitalise the tag names, rearrange the attributes, or even transform the elements to some valid HTML element or surround it with HTML elements to make it a valid document.

If you want the result as a self closing tag, you need to put an XHTML document (or perhaps an HTML5 document) in the iframe, otherwise it will be returned as HTML, which doesn't have any self closing tags.